# Building own letterhead

Tags: letterhead

I'm building my own letterhead with LaTeX.

I would have:

- a first page with header and footer
- from second page ahead, just header, but different from first page.

I've already built a one page letterhead with fancy class (I have a header and a footer with images and text)

But, what I'm unable to do is to change the footer and header starting from the second page of the document.

So, I think I should understood when first page end, and the use a new header formatting.
Isn't it?

How can I do that?

Comment: It's worth to take a look at the »scrlttr2« class from the [KOMA Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) bundle.

Answer (score 3):

What you should do do is to define a header and footer for the document and re-define the header and footer for the first page. Here's a snippet from a `.cls` files I wrote a while ago. Some of the variables, spacings, etc are specific to my use but it should give you a rough idea of what to do.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[CE]{\textit{\@title}}
\fancyhead[CO]{\sc \@runningname}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headsep}{10pt}

\fancypagestyle{first}{% 
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\fancyhead[C]{ }
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{\today}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}%
```

You can also go though the [documentation for the package](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fancyhdr.html) (fancyhdr). I found it very helpful.